# Trouble with e-mail in Corona

Tags: email, lua, coronasdk

So I made a picture to be clicked in order to send an e-mail to me from the app, but it seems not to be able to show me that in the simulator? I made the picture hide itself, just to see if the function was being executed, and it was, it's just the pop-up itself which is not working. Here is my code:

```
local contact = display.newImage("questionMark.png")
contact.x = display.contentWidth - 20
contact.y = display.contentHeight - 20

local function contactMe (event)
local options =
{
    to = "joepshoulak@me.com",
    subject = "Feedback",
    body = "Test",
}
native.showPopup("mail", options)
contact.isVisible = false
end

contact:addEventListener("tap", contactMe)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not stated in the manual unfortunately, but it is on some forum posts and blog posts, that e-mail does not work in Simulator...

Mostly, because it works by using the operating system support for a operation, Android do it by "activity" when you ask for a "e-mail" activity it searches on its system for all registered e-mail apps and ask the user what one he wants, and iOS just call the iOS default e-mail app...

Windows and Mac OS the closest they have is a "default program" for some things, but they have no clear API for that, so Corona has nothing to use, so no, it is not supported in the simulator, and probably never will be supported at all, excepting maybe in Windows 8 and that is a very big maybe.